# How to remove certain Aspell dictionaries?

Tags: aspell

If I run **aspell dump dicts**, I get the following dictionaries listed. If I just want to keep en_GB and en_US, how can I get rid of the others? I've been through the documentation [here](http://aspell.net/man-html/Working-With-Dictionaries.html#Working-With-Dictionaries) but don't see how to do this.

```
en
en_CA
en_CA-w-accents
en_GB
en_GB-w-accents
en_US
en_US-w-accents
es
fr-40
fr-60
fr
fr-80
fr_CH-40
fr_CH
fr_CH-60
fr_CH-80
fr_FR-40
fr_FR-60
fr_FR
fr_FR-80
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Linux primarily but I need it for Windows too.

Comment: I'm going to ask this on SO too. I didn't think it was appropriate there, but there seems to be lots of aspell questions there.